# PHP, make the page automatically detect changes made by the admin

Tags: php

just wanna ask your opinions regarding this scenario that I want to achieve, 
I have an admin site and members area. Now, if the admin deleted the id of the current user who is logged-in on the members area page, the members_area.php  will automatically refresh and redirect them to the login page. Is this possible by only using php, I don't want to use javascript/jQuery to achieve this :)

- Please feel free to comment if you think my question is not that clear.

Comment: No, it is not possible. PHP is executed when the page is requested. Once it serves the content it is no longer running. JS runs client side and can send requests to PHP scripts.

Comment: ohh, so i need to use js.. I thought this would be possible, because in the members_area page, I am only printing their username and credentials, now if the admin deleted the credential of the certain user, members_area.php will refresh or if the user refresh the page, it will just prompt them to the login page/sign-up page

Comment: using only `php` users will not notice their credential until they refresh the page. so if it's OK for you that when the admin deletes the credential, the user will not notice it immediately, and after the first USER refresh they will notice, `php` will do it. but if you need immediate action, you have to use `js` and `ajax` to take care of it.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the inputs, I made it by having adding simple if statement in my members_area.php wherein if they refresh it and if there is no fetched data for the current logged-on user, they will be redirected.. Thanks for the ideas :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work on the next refresh **initiated by the user**. If you want  auto refresh you have to use some javascript to validate the credentials from time to time or listen to push notifications (websockets)

Comment: Thanks, I read your comment and I what you've said, the refresh initiated by the user works :D